# Code is heuristically unreachable when getting object from cache

Tags: c#, resharper, fxcop

I have the following code, the idea is simple if the object is in cache get it, if not then retrieve it from the data source and save it into cache, I am using resharper and I got this warning but cant understand why

```
 public static ModulosPorUsuario GetModulesForUser(string identityname)
        {
            // It needs to be cached for every user because every user can have different modules enabled.
            var cachekeyname = "ApplicationModulesPerUser|" + identityname;

            var cache = CacheConnectionHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
            ModulosPorUsuario modulosUsuario;

            //get object from cache
            string modulosUsuariosString = cache.StringGet(cachekeyname);

            // ReSharper disable once ConditionIsAlwaysTrueOrFalse
            if (modulosUsuariosString != null)
            {
                //conver string to our object
                modulosUsuario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModulosPorUsuario>(modulosUsuariosString);
                return modulosUsuario;
            }
            // ReSharper disable once HeuristicUnreachableCode
            modulosUsuario = DbApp.ModulosPorUsuario.Where(p => p.Email == identityname).FirstOrDefault();

            //convert object to json string
            modulosUsuariosString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modulosUsuario);

            //save string in cache
            cache.StringSet(cachekeyname, modulosUsuariosString, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(SettingsHelper.CacheModuleNames));
            return modulosUsuario;
        }
```

Comment: Could it be that cache.StringGet always returns a string and so your if condition will always be true making the rest of the code unreachable?

Comment: I think @user995219 has it right, especially because you also disabled the Resharper warning telling you that. You probably want to do `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modulosUsuariosString))`, though it really depends on what `StringGet()` returns for a cache miss (and I'd argue that `null` is "more correct" than `string.Empty`, though still not a great cache API since it means you can't cache the result as `null`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's quite a lot going on here, but the bottom line, this is a ReSharper bug - the value can certainly be null, and I have a much smaller example proving it.

First, let's figure out what's going on in your code. I had to dig a little bit into the [`StackExchange.Redis`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) library that you're using. Your `cache` object is, in fact, an `IDatabase`, which is implemented by the [`RedisDatabase`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/RedisDatabase.cs) class. The [`StringGet`](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/RedisDatabase.cs#L1428-L1432) method that you're using returns a `RedisValue`, which is a struct. This, by itself, would make perfect sense why ReSharper tells you it can never be null - value types can't!

However, you're putting the result into a `string` variable! This works because the `RedisValue` struct defines a bunch of [implicit operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) to convert the value into the requested type. In case of a string, notice that if the blob is empty, an empty string is returned:

[**RedisValue.cs**](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/RedisValue.cs)

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts the value to a String
/// </summary>
public static implicit operator string(RedisValue value)
{
    var valueBlob = value.valueBlob;
    if (valueBlob == IntegerSentinel)
        return Format.ToString(value.valueInt64);
    if (valueBlob == null) return null;

    if (valueBlob.Length == 0) return "";
    try
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(valueBlob);
    }
    catch
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(valueBlob);
    }
}
```

But from this code it's obvious that the string can be `null` as well.

This makes ReSharper incorrect to flag that line, and it can be reproduced with a smaller example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string value = MyStruct.GetValue();
    if (value == null) // <- ReSharper complains here, but the value is null!
    {
        return;
    }
}

public struct MyStruct
{
    public static MyStruct GetValue() => new MyStruct();

    public static implicit operator string(MyStruct s)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I [reported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-446326) this issue to JetBrains, they will fix it.

In the meantime, you might want to keep that comment, disabling ReSharper warning.

Comment: How did you know that's the library being used?!

Comment: @AakashM magic :P But honestly, I just googled `CacheConnectionHelper.Connection.GetDatabase`, and saw that it was referred to in various "Azure Redis Cache" posts.